# Squash merge commit

Tags: git, github, merge

I have pull request on github to which I pushed some commits. It's been idle for some time and now it has merge conflicts.
So I merged my feature branch with the master branch, resolved the conflicts and pushed it.
Now I want to squash/remove the merge commit that has been created.
I tried `git rebase -i` but there are some commits between my last commit and the merge commit.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're on the right track, and now have 2 options Look at the picture:

```
A1 — A2 — A3 — A4
 \
  F1 — F2 — F3
```

where A1..A4 is the mainline of the project and F1..F3 is your feature branch submitted in the PR. Now however F3 can't be easily merged with A4 due to conflicting changes.

You could create merging commit F4:

```
A1 — A2 — A3 — A4
 \              \
  F1 — F2 — F3 — F4
```

and then submit F4 as PR. In this case the repo owner could take F4 and merge it to the mainline, so the project history will look like this:

```
A1 — A2 — A3 — A4 — A5 
 \              \ /
  F1 — F2 — F3 — F4
```

Essentially, A5 sourcetree will be equal to F4 and in some workflows A5 is exactly F4.

Alternatively, you could checkout F3 (`git checkout <feature_branch>; git reset --hard F3;`) and then use `git rebase -i A4` to reapply changes from your feature branch over the current project HEAD. You need to resolve all the conflicts one by one and in the end you'll get the following commits structure:

```
A1 — A2 — A3 — A4
                 \
                  F1' — F2' — F3'
```

and then you may forcibly update your repository fork with `git push -f ...` and then re-new the PR.

Comment: Great. So rebasing instead of merging just doesn't create an extra commit (earlier I merged the branches before rebasing to try squash the merge commit).

Btw which one is the standard norm in such a scenario, rebase or merge?

Comment: Well, rebasing is a dangerous practice if you have already published commits. This is because technically F1 != F1', F2 != F2' and so on. These commit pairs _may_ have the same source tree, but in any case they would have different parents so from the git point of view, these commits are different. So if you publish a commit and someone use this commit as a base of his/her work, then, after your rebase, he/she has to rebase as well.

Comment: But for cases when you're sure that noone except you uses a particular commit, you may do whatever you need with a commit: amend it, rebase, even remove completely. It's ok to rebase commits from short-lived forks on GitHub created solely to make a PR.